# Can't get memcache to return value

Tags: php, memcached

I've taken a bit of a memcache script that i've used previously without issue, but on the new page, I don't get any response.

the memcache is in a function which is included from another page. 
what I do is put the md5 hash the mysql query and store that as the key for the memcached data. if the key isn't in memcache, then I go, create the data, put it into memcache and return it.

I think the code is fairly simple. Here are the important bits (it's a large page creating the output, so you don't need all that, though the 'return' I think is important as I fear that might be where I'm screwing up.

I call the function with

```
$outList.= outData($getList);
```

where $getList is a mysql query

The $outList function is

```
<?php

@$memcache = new Memcache;
@$memcache->connect("localhost",11211);

function outData($getList)
{
    $memVal = @$memcache->get(MD5($getList));
    if($memVal=='')
    {
        $results=mysql_query($getList)or die(mysql_error());

        // then I do a bunch of stuff with the data
        @$memcache->set(MD5($getList), $memVal, false, 60000);
    } 
    return $memVal;
}
```

I can display all the stuff to create $memVal, but i suspect the error is in the if line, but the same code is used on another page without issues.

Anything look wrong with this?

Comment: Would be great help if you remove the @ while debugging.....

Comment: This is also why I run my development environment with the most strict errors *and warnings* displayed.  I want to see everything that PHP finds even slightly not-right about the code. A warning is an error that will just come back later to bite you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with all those @'s suppressing errors, there's no way to know what is failing.

I ran it - sans the @'s and the answer popped right up though - on the line:

```
$memVal = @$memcache->get(MD5($getList));
#Notice: Undefined variable: memcache in /home/topbit/736160.php on line 9
```

Where does it get the variable $memcache ?  It's not passed into the function.

Comment: sorry about that, i was using the @ to test when memcache failed or didn't connect. Of course, I should have known that was supressing the error that I should have seen. My bad :(

Answer (score 2):

The problem is scope. When in a function, variables in global scope do not automatically get passed on, you will have to add them as parameters to the function.

```
function outData($memcache, $getList)
```